# List of listing showing in one line

Tags: listings

In the pdf the list of listing is showing in one line like this:

```
1
Example of json object for each tweet34 2 Tweets and cluster identifier per
user34
```

Here `1` and `2` are number and `34` is the page number. Both are in a same page with different `caption` and `label`. The Code for list of listing i used:

```
\pdfbookmark[1]{\lstlistlistingname}{lol}

\lstlistoflistings
```

How can i do this:

```
1 Example of json object for each tweet  34 
2 Tweets and cluster identifier per user 34
```

Here is my two listing code:

```
\begin{listing}
    \begin{minted}[frame=single,
    framesep=3mm,
    linenos=true,
    xleftmargin=21pt,
    tabsize=4]{js}
    {     
    "_id": "tweet id"
    "user_id" : "ID of the user" 
    }
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Example of json object for each tweet} 
    \label{list:first_json}
\end{listing}
```

and

```
\begin{listing}
    \begin{minted}[frame=single,
    framesep=3mm,
    linenos=true,
    xleftmargin=21pt,
    tabsize=4]{js}
    {     
    "_id": "json object id",
    "user_id": "ID of the user"
    }
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Tweets and cluster identifier per user} 
    \label{list:second_json}
\end{listing}
```

Comment: Can you make a complete example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: please, see the edit.

Comment: That's not a complete document .. But try `\listoflistings`, and not `\lstlistoflistings` (the latter is from the `listings` package, while you're using `minted`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary: Use `\listoflistings` instead of `\lstlistoflistings`.

---

The problem can be reproduced by the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted,listings}
\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings

\begin{listing}
    \begin{minted}{js}
    a
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Example of json object for each tweet} 
\end{listing}


\begin{listing}
    \begin{minted}{c}
    s
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Tweets and cluster identifier per user} 
\end{listing} 
\end{document}
```

Which outputs

[image: output with \lstlistoflistings]

What you're doing wrong is mixing environments and macros from two different packages. The `listing` environment is defined by `minted`, but `\lstlistoflistings` is defined by `listings`. You should be using `\listoflistings`, which is defined by `minted`. Doing so gives

[image: output with \listoflistings]

All `\listof` macros read information from temporary files, but both `minted` and `listings` write caption information to a `.lol` file, so `\lstlistoflistings` reads the file generated by `minted`, and the content of this is obviously structured differently to what `\lstlistoflistings` expects, and the output is wrong.